# Changes in item meta_data on payment_completed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want change add/change a meta_data in order item after complete a payment

is somethink like add a custom field with random number.

How I can make that ?

I dont found how

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Mark as on-hold (we're awaiting the cheque)
    if ( 'yes' == $this->debug ) {
        $this->log->add( 'Compra', "IPN Response Loggin test" );
    }
    $order->get_items();
    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            if ( ! $item['qty'] ) {
                continue;
            }
            // Any information about function to edit meta data in item ?
        }
    }
    $order->payment_complete();
    // Reduce stock levels
    $order->reduce_order_stock();
    // Remove cart
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Return thankyou redirect
    return array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `payment_complete()` method in the Order abstract class you will see the `woocommerce_payment_complete` action hook. If you want to run something when the payment is completed, then you would attach your function to this hook. Without really understanding what you are doing, the following will simply add a random number (not necessarily unique) to each item in the order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_27852832_item_data' );
function so_27852832_item_data( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $id => $item ) {         
            wc_update_order_item_meta( $id, '_random_number', rand() );         
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `wc_update_order_item_meta` for this purpose.

Try this

```
if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $id => $item ) {
        if ( ! $item['qty'] ) {
            continue;
        }
        // Any information about function to edit meta data in item ?           
        wc_update_order_item_meta( $id, 'your meta key', 'new value' );         
    }
}
```